# Looking for method like ParentNode.append but replaces the contents of the ParentNode rather than adding to it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

As the title says I am trying to replace the contents of a (an?) HTML element with a table I have generated.

Currently when the button is clicked it adds the generated table to the contents of div `tableDiv`. I would like it to replace the contents of `tableDiv`. I had a look at `replaceChild` but you need to know the old child and it threw an error that a list of children wasn't the same as a child when I tried to use `childNodes` to find the current children to replace (also that felt like a very janky way to do it).

I also tried `document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML` but TypeScript threw an error about innerHTML only accepting strings not HTML elements. (actual like of code was `div.innerHTML = table`)

The code is below. I am using TypeScript not plain JavaScript if that changes anything. Sorry you can't run it I couldn't find anywhere online that supports DOM editing.

```js
function genGrid(size) {
  console.log("genGrid called");
  var div = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      //let cellText = document.createTextNode(`${size*i+j}`);
      cell.append("" + (size * i + j));
      var id = document.createAttribute("id");
      id.value = "" + (size * i + j);
      cell.setAttributeNode(id);
    }
  }
  div.append(table);
  console.log(table);
  div.append("test");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--<script src="latticePaths.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="latticePaths.css" /> -->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slideBar">
      <!--slider for size: (not yet implemented)-->
    </div>
    <div id="tableDiv">
      <button type="button" onClick="genGrid(6)">Generate the grid</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first delete all the elements inside the `div` variable using `div.textContent = "";`. Then you can append the `table` inside `div`. Just give it a try to the code below.

```js
const genGrid = (size) => {
  console.log("genGrid called");
  var div = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      //let cellText = document.createTextNode(`${size*i+j}`);
      cell.append("" + (size * i + j));
      var id = document.createAttribute("id");
      id.value = "" + (size * i + j);
      cell.setAttributeNode(id);
    }
  }
  div.textContent = "";
  div.append(table);
  console.log(table);
  div.append("test");
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    genGrid(6);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slideBar">
    <!--slider for size: (not yet implemented)-->
  </div>
  <div id="tableDiv">
    <button type="button" id="button">Generate the grid</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using a lambda and events?

Comment: Good shot but for it to work you will have to re-append the button or move it outside the div

Comment: I used event listener because while testing in js fiddle with typescript, for some reason, the onClick event in the button throws some error. And for the arrow function, it's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here: I re-appended the button so you can generate the grid one more than once.

```js
const genGrid = (size) => {
  console.log("genGrid called");
  var div = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      //let cellText = document.createTextNode(`${size*i+j}`);
      cell.append("" + (size * i + j +1));
      var id = document.createAttribute("id");
      id.value = "" + (size * i + j + 1);
      cell.setAttributeNode(id);
    }
  }
    div.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" id=\"button\">Generate the grid</button>";  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
      genGrid(100);
  });
  
  div.append(table);
  console.log(table);
  div.append("test");
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    genGrid(6);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slideBar">
    <!--slider for size: (not yet implemented)-->
  </div>
  <div id="tableDiv">
    <button type="button" id="button">Generate the grid</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a (little-known?) [`ParentNode.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/replaceChildren) method that does exactly that.

```js
function genGrid(size) {
  var div = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.append("" + (size * i + j));
      var id = document.createAttribute("id");
      id.value = "" + (size * i + j);
      cell.setAttributeNode(id);
    }
  }
  div.replaceChildren(table);
  div.append("test");
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", (evt) => genGrid(evt.target.value) );
genGrid(8);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slideBar">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="8">
  </div>
  <div id="tableDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Though beware, you may need a [polyfill](https://github.com/yuzhe-han/ParentNode-replaceChildren) for older browsers like InternetExplorer.

Comment: The replaceChildren method gives the error 'replaceChild does not exist on type HTMLElement'

Comment: Well just extend the Node interface so it's up to date.